# Context-switch and thread execution on different CPU cores 

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, context-switch, memory-barriers

From my another question on SO I found out that its possible that following simple method

```
  void B()
  {
    if (_complete)
    {
      Console.WriteLine (_answer);
    }
  }
```

may be executed on different CPUs if context switch happens between if and console writeline call.. This is news to me so I am wondering now when can single thread code become switched for another CPU and why it may make sense in such simple case as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, a context switch is the OS "freezing" a thread where it is, so that another thread can get some CPU time. When the first thread is "thawed", there's no requirement that it continue running on the CPU where it was previously running. That detail is up to the OS to decide.

For example, if when the thread is thawed there is a full core that is unused which happens to differ from the previous core that the thread was running on, it would be wasteful not to use the free core.

Comment: +1 - and will just add you can set Affinity for a thread to ensure that it does get sent back to the same processor/core - although in general there is no need to.

Comment: @Andras Good point, you *can* set processor affinity. My point was just that it's not the case by default.

Comment: You can set processor affinity either through an API call or via the Task Manager.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity.aspx  However as others have said, that generally should not matter.  I have done that through the task manager when doing CPU intensive rendering to ensure that one (of 12) cores is NOT usable by the rendering software so that the Windows UI remains responsive.

Comment: thanks guys this is useful and on topic, makes perfect sense to me now

Answer (score 6):

> when can single thread code become switched for another CPU

This can happen at any time.  That being said, you should really, for practical purposes, never care.  This is a function of any multitasking operating system.

> why it may make sense in such simple case as above?

It doesn't help *your code* at all.  It does allow the operating system to better balance and handle other processes running on the system.

Comment: both answers are good and you were 5 sec faster I think but I think ill mark dlev as an answer, cause it got affinity discussion which is interesting

Answer (score 0):

> when can single thread code become switched for another CPU

Any time.

And remember, the CPU/OS does not see your code. It sees machine instructions, which is very different from the code you write - machine instructions are usually(always ?) atomically executed, but your program can be preemted/reschedulet in between any instruction.

> and why it may make sense in such simple case as above?

On a commodity operating systems there is [preemtive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) scheduling, your program is not the only code that runs. The OS might need to halt your code to let some other process/thread/service/interrupt handler run.

And when your process gets to run again, perhaps the CPU it ran on previously is occupied, while there's another CPU free to use - so the OS schedules your process on that CPU.